# Group By with count doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use group by with count function but this doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    projects.AgencyId,
    projects.ProgramId,
    count(projects.ProjStatusByMin) as status,
    projects.ProjStatusByMin 
from 
    projects 
where 
    projects.AgencyId=40 
group by 
    projects.ProjStatusByMin
```

This above code works in MySQL perfectly now i want to achieve the same thing in SQL Server.

```
Select 
    ProjStatusByMin,
    COUNT(ProjStatusByMin) [projstatus] 
from 
    Projects
where 
    AgencyId=40 
group by 
    ProjStatusByMin,AgencyId,ProjId
```

However if i select a single column like the bellow code then group by work

```
Select 
    ProjStatusByMin,
    COUNT(ProjStatusByMin) [projstatus] 
from 
    Projects
where 
    AgencyId=40 
group by 
    ProjStatusByMin
```

Now how can I achieve group by with multi column selected?

Comment: In most oher dbs other than mysql, you need all columns in the select also in the GROUP BY,IF you dont use aggregate functions(Count,SUM,etc)

Comment: mySQL extends the group by clause to allow your original SQL to work.  However, SQL server doesn't do this.  There's risk in using mySQL extensions, that you may not have been aware of.

Comment: "Works perfectly"? Really? Which AgencyId and ProgramId do you get, if there are multiple for a given ProjStatusByMin? Is it the one you expect? How do you know?

Comment: I modified the code and i got what i was expecting. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add all the columns (except for the one in the count function) to the group by clause.

```
SELECT projects.AgencyId,projects.ProgramId,count(projects.ProjStatusByMin) as status,
projects.ProjStatusByMin 
from projects 
where projects.AgencyId=40 
group by projects.ProjStatusByMin, projects.AgencyId,projects.ProgramId
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you have to write all the column names in group by clause which you are going to select in the select statement.